# Custom Image in navigationbar hiding the custom navigationbar buttons

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

First of all I explain what i am doing. I created a navigation based application. I have to add a custom image in the navigationbar. I added the image by using -

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:image atIndex:0]`;

After this i added two custom buttons left and right to the navigation bar of the same view.I have another view and on this view i also added two custom buttons left and right to the navigation bar. All is fine till now but as i navigate to my second view my custom buttons that i am adding to the navigation controller on viewwillappear doesn't show. I used this code to add custom buttons to navigation bar -

```
UIBarButtonItem *customHome = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: buttonHome];
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:customHome];
```

Please suggest what's wrong in this. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the `navigationItem` on the navigation controller instead of the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you have embedded your `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController` then in `viewDidLoad` of the View Controller you could, for example, make the title a `UISearchBar` (that you dragged to the `UIViewController` in Xcode IB) and put 2 buttons on the right like this:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *componentsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"components" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(componentsButtonTapped:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(settingsButtonTapped:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:componentsButton, settingsButton, nil];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
```

The issue here is the distinction between `UINavigationController`, which manages `UINavigationBar`, and `UINavigationItem`, which you and `UINavigationController` co-manage. (Don't forget the `UINavigationBarDelegate` protocol, which has little used but useful methods.)